# Passing lists/arrays as inputs for scikit learn models

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I have this data frame:

```
| col1         | col2        | col3      | col4      | label
-------------------------------------------------------------
[1,2,3,4,5,6]  | [1,2]       | [1,2,3,4] | [1,2,4]   | 1
[5,6,7,8]      | [5,6,7,8,9] | [1,4]     | [1,2,3,4] | 0
```

Ideally, I would like to load each column as separate variables. In this case, each column represents tokenized words. My goal is to classify if col1 & col2 is a fuzzy match with col3 & col4.

In previous implementations of sci-kit that I have done, the data is structured something like this:

```
| col1         | col2        | col3      | col4      | label
------------------------------------------------------------- 
 1             | 2           | 4         | 0         | 1
 8             | 9           | 1         | 2         | 0
```

In these cases, it is easy to drop the label and call `df.to_numpy()` and load into the models.

In my case, I have attempted this by combining each column into one array but I run into issues as each column can have arrays of vastly differing lengths. (0 to ~5000) I have tried filling these arrays with `nan` or 0 to create arrays of the same length as the maximum length in the set. But it blows up the dataset size greatly as the total amount of records in the set is 1M.

I have looked into using PCA to restrict each array to the same length but run into errors as the dimensions are 1D instead of 2D. Additionally, this does not solve my problem of each column containing arrays. (if that is an issue to worry about)

I know this is geared towards a more fundamental / high level guidance question so any additional guidance/ docs would be super helpful!

Comment: How about one-hot encoding each column array? Putting aside the thousands of features that would be generated, would you still be able to perform your fuzzy classification algorithm?